# If one row in a dataframe contains a certain value, convert all entries in the row to that value

Tags: r

I have a dataframe looking like this:

```
b1 <- c(0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1)
b2 <- c(0,0,1,1,"NA",0,1,1)
b3 <- c(0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1)
b4 <- c(0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1)
b5 <- c(0,0,"NA",1,0,0,1,1)
b6 <- c(0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1)
b7 <- c(0,0,1,1,0,"NA",1,1)
b8 <- c(0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1)
df <- data.frame(b1,b2,b3,b4,b5,b6,b7,b8)
df
```

I want to change any row containing at least one `"NA"` to be containing all `"NA"`s, so the example would look like this:

```
b1 <- c(0,0,"NA",1,"NA","NA",1,1)
b2 <- c(0,0,"NA",1,"NA","NA",1,1)
b3 <- c(0,0,"NA",1,"NA","NA",1,1)
b4 <- c(0,0,"NA",1,"NA","NA",1,1)
b5 <- c(0,0,"NA",1,"NA","NA",1,1)
b6 <- c(0,0,"NA",1,"NA","NA",1,1)
b7 <- c(0,0,"NA",1,"NA","NA",1,1)
b8 <- c(0,0,"NA",1,"NA","NA",1,1)
df <- data.frame(b1,b2,b3,b4,b5,b6,b7,b8)
df
```

I have written this function to achieve this, but it doesn't work:

```
NAconverter <- function(x){
df$x <- if(df$b1 == "NA" && df$b2 == "NA" && df$b3 == "NA" && df$b4 == "NA"  && df$b5 == "NA" && df$b6 == "NA" && df$b7 == "NA" && df$b8 == "NA", "NA")
}
```

I would then run the function for each column, e.g

```
NAconverter(b1)
```

Thanks very much for any help.

Comment: `NA` should be created without quotes as it will be easier to use `is.na` or `complete cases`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I have changed this in my data now!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the example data, `NA` was created as character strings, So, you can try

```
df[rowSums(df=='NA')!=0,] <- NA
```

If the `NAs` were real, ie, create the dataset as

```
b1 <- c(0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1)
b2 <- c(0,0,1,1,NA,0,1,1)
b3 <- c(0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1)
b4 <- c(0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1)
b5 <- c(0,0,NA,1,0,0,1,1)
b6 <- c(0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1)
b7 <- c(0,0,1,1,0,NA,1,1)
b8 <- c(0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1)
df <- data.frame(b1,b2,b3,b4,b5,b6,b7,b8)
```

Note that this will also change the class of the columns from `factor` to `numeric`

```
df[!!rowSums(is.na(df)),] <- NA
```

Or

```
 df[Reduce(`|`,lapply(df, is.na)),] <- NA
 df
 #   b1 b2 b3 b4 b5 b6 b7 b8
 #1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
 #2  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
 #3 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
 #4  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1
 #5 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
 #6 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
 #7  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1
 #8  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1
```

#### Update

Suppose there are columns that should be left out for example

```
a <- letters[1:8]
df <- data.frame(a, b1,b2,b3,b4,b5,b6,b7,b8)
```

Here, I am getting the index by leaving out the first column ('a')

```
df[-1][!!rowSums(is.na(df[-1])),] <- NA
```

Comment: Thanks, this works, but my data actually has some other columns that I left out to simplify it, and the other columns get converted to NA as well. Is there an easy way to just focus on those 8 columns?

Comment: @Margins Updated with an example